# Is it possible to modify the reference of an argument in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

Not sure if the terminology in the title is 100% correct, but what I mean is easily illustrated by this example:

```
class MyClass{
  String str = '';  
  MyClass(this.str);
}


void main() {
  MyClass obj1 = MyClass('obj1 initial');

  print(obj1.str);

  doSomething(obj1);  
  print(obj1.str);

  doSomethingElse(obj1);
  print(obj1.str);
}



void doSomething(MyClass obj){
  obj.str = 'obj1 new string';
}

void doSomethingElse(MyClass obj){
  obj = MyClass('obj1 new object');
}
```

This will print

```
obj1 initial
obj1 new string
obj1 new string
```

But what if I wanted `doSomethingElse()` to actually modify what `obj1` is referencing, so that the output would be:

```
obj1 initial
obj1 new string
obj1 new object
```

Is this possible in Dart, and if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Dart does not pass arguments by reference. (Without something like C++'s complex type system and rules, it's not clear how it would work if the caller didn't bind the argument to a variable.)

You instead could add a level of indirection (i.e., by putting `obj1` inside another object, such as a `List`, `Map`, or your own class).  Another possibility would be to make `doSomethingElse` a nested function, and then it could directly access and modify variables in the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 4):

You have a reference problem in that function,

When you call `doSomethingElse(obj1)` in main your,

`MyObject obj` parameter referencing the **obj1 value**,

then `obj` you're referencing the `MyClass('obj1 new objcet')`,

and you're not changing the `obj1` reference in the main

```
void doSomethingElse(MyClass obj){ // let's say we gave the parameter obj1
  // here obj referencing the obj1 value
  obj = MyClass('obj1 new object');
  //and then it is referencing the MyClass('obj1 new object') value
  //nothing change for obj1 it still referencing the same value
}
```

You can return that object and give reference to that object like this,

```
class MyClass {
  String str = '';
  MyClass(this.str);
}

void main() {
  MyClass obj1 = MyClass('obj1 initial');

  print(obj1.str);

  doSomething(obj1);
  print(obj1.str);

  obj1 = doSomethingElse();
  print(obj1.str);
}

void doSomething(MyClass obj) {
  obj.str = 'obj1 new string';
}

MyClass doSomethingElse() {
  return MyClass('obj1 new object');
}
```

output : [image]